# Convert an int to time()

Tags: php, laravel, wordpress

I want to send a reminder email “x” days after an initial email was send.

The admin can choose after how many days they want to send a reminder (after the date of the initial mail).

This amount is stored in this function and returns an integer (for example 14)

```
public function getAmountDayReminder(): int
{
    return get_field('send_reminder_after_amount_day', $this->getId());
}
```

The date/time of that the initial email was send is stored in this function

```
public function setWasNotified()
{
    update_post_meta($this->getId(), self::META_WAS_NOTIFIED, time());
}
```

Now I want to write an if statement so that the reminder will be send out “x” days after the date of the initial mail was send.

I guess it will look something like this:

```
if(!$entry->wasNotified() && !$entry->wasReminded()) {
    $remindDate = $entry->setwasNotified() + $this->getAmountDayReminder();
    if ($remindDate === //current time) {
        $entry->remind();
    }
}
```

This won’t work because I have to covert the output of `setwasNotified()` and `getAmountDayReminder()` so that I can add them.

Is this a good solution and how would I execute this exactly?

Comment: Look at wp-cron. https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_schedule_event/

Comment: Well if `// current time` is your issue then as the other rimes look like timestamps (an integer) then use `time()` and `// current time`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use the [DateTime modify](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.modify.php) to add getAmountDayReminder() to the time where the first notification has been sent and then compare this to the current time.

Something like that:

```
<?php
$reminded = DateTime::createFromFormat( 'U', $entry->setwasNotified());

$now = new DateTime();

if ($now > $reminded->modify($this->getAmountDayReminder() .' day')) {
    print('Need to send reminder');
}
else {
    print('Do not send reminder');
}
```

Do not forget to store whether you already sent the reminder.
And doing such things in a cron job is probably a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

- Convert The previous date into time stamp , call it $lastNotified
- Convert days into timestamp after multiplying (24x60x60x$numberofdays_after) Seconds: called it $daysAfter
- Add $lastNotified and $daysAfter
- now compare the recent timestamp time() === ($lastNotified+$daysAfter)
- if current time is equals to the ($lastNotified+$daysAfter) send New Notification and Save current time stamp as $lastNotified

For your code:

```
if(!$entry->wasNotified() && !$entry->wasReminded()) {
    $remindDate = $entry->setwasNotified() + (24*60*60*$this->getAmountDayReminder());
    if ($remindDate === time()) {
        $entry->remind();
    }
}
```